# End all processes started by GUI at exit (daemon = True not working)

Tags: python, user-interface, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

How can you ensure that all processes are shutdown whenever a user ends the main program UI?  I have tried setting the processes to `daemon = True` but this is not working.  I have seen other threads state that you should use a signal and continually check if a "quit" signal has been emitted, but this doesn't make sense to me in regards to where to place this script since the GUI code should no longer be executing if the GUI is now gone.

How would the process know if the GUI is gone in this case: (where `sys.exit(app.exec_())` is executed)

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import multiprocessing as mp
import sys
import time

def f(data):
    for i in range(0,10**5):
        data[0] += 1
        time.sleep(.1)

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.top_level_layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.centralwidget.setLayout(self.top_level_layout)
        self.process_button = QtGui.QPushButton("Start Process")
        self.top_level_layout.addWidget(self.process_button, 0, 0)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.process_button, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.start_process)

        self.processlist = list()
        self.manager = mp.Manager()
        self.data = self.manager.list([1])
        for i in range(0,10):
            self.processlist.append(mp.Process(target=f, args=(self.data,)))
            self.processlist[-1].daemon = True

    def start_process(self):
        for p in self.processlist:
            p.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.  You can redefine a `closeEvent` function in a `QWidget` object.  Like so:

```
def closeEvent(self, event):
    for p in self.processlist:
        p.terminate()
```

Here is an updated code snippet:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import multiprocessing as mp
import sys
import time

def f(data):
    for i in range(0,10**5):
        data[0] += 1
        time.sleep(.1)

class MainWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.centralwidget = QtGui.QWidget(self)
        self.top_level_layout = QtGui.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.centralwidget.setLayout(self.top_level_layout)
        self.process_button = QtGui.QPushButton("Start Process")
        self.top_level_layout.addWidget(self.process_button, 0, 0)
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.process_button, QtCore.SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.start_process)

        self.processlist = list()
        self.manager = mp.Manager()
        self.data = self.manager.list([1])
        for i in range(0, 10):
            self.processlist.append(mp.Process(target=f, args=(self.data,)))
            self.processlist[-1].daemon = True

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        for p in self.processlist:
            p.terminate()

    def start_process(self):
        for p in self.processlist:
            p.start()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```